# forced fixed intercept but lattice plot showed random intercept

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I was running a model and something weird pops up.

1. I ran a multi-level regression using the code below:

```
summary(model11 <- lmer(between ~ groupMCpres + (1+ groupMCpres | group), 
                        data = survey2, REML = FALSE))
```

It returned Singular Fit (and failed convergence), and I checked the output, it seems like there's no variance for intercept between groups (or is very close to 0).

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: between ~ groupMCpres + (1+groupMCpres | team)
   Data: survey2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   441.4    457.3   -214.7    429.4       98 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.22860 -0.58607  0.00006  0.58475  2.88015 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 team     (Intercept) 0.000    0.000        
          groupMCpres 3.745    1.935     NaN
 Residual             3.144    1.773        
Number of obs: 104, groups:  team, 26

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.9589     0.1739 84.7970  22.769   <2e-16 ***
groupMCpres   1.2473     0.6198 15.9694   2.012   0.0614 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
groupMCpres -0.002
convergence code: 0
singular fit

Warning message:
Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -9.7e-03
```

So I proceeded to fit the intercept to 0 and see what happened.

Here's what I have got:

```
summary(model11 <- lmer(between ~ groupMCpres + (0 + groupMCpres | group), 
                        data = survey2, REML = FALSE))
```

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: between ~ groupMCpres + (0 + groupMCpres | team)
   Data: survey2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   437.4    448.0   -214.7    429.4      100 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.22860 -0.58607  0.00006  0.58475  2.88015 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 team     groupMCpres 3.745    1.935   
 Residual             3.144    1.773   
Number of obs: 104, groups:  team, 26

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.9589     0.1739 84.7970  22.769   <2e-16 ***
groupMCpres   1.2473     0.6198 15.9694   2.012   0.0614 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
groupMCpres -0.002
```

The model fitted well without singular fit, which makes sense.

However, when I tried to plot lattice plot, it appeared that there's actually random intercepts - may I know what Is going on here?

[image]

Also, the slopes do not seem to correspond to what I printed.

```
coef(model1)

$group
   (Intercept) groupMCpres
1     3.958911  2.95074502
2     3.958911  0.98143197
3     3.958911  0.78963610
4     3.958911 -1.21935347
5     3.958911  3.24950223
6     3.958911  1.99797635
8     3.958911 -0.02415999
9     3.958911 -0.05083597
10    3.958911  2.96807428
11    3.958911  0.76744041
12    3.958911  0.80973249
13    3.958911 -0.28954981
14    3.958911  2.36726728
15    3.958911 -0.64904521
17    3.958911  1.58043967
18    3.958911  1.98931618
19    3.958911  2.17787207
20    3.958911  3.09473245
21    3.958911  2.01111319
22    3.958911  1.15876189
23    3.958911  1.44282914
24    3.958911  1.05631488
32    3.958911  0.10617548
34    3.958911  1.15385811
35    3.958911  1.93717348
36    3.958911  0.07188506
```

This is so strange and I hope anyone can help enlighten.

Comment: The output of `coef(model1)` indicates that there are no random intercepts but only random slopes - could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Hi Dimitris, thank you for the reply. I think i meant the original model, when i run it, it showed singular fit (in that the variance for intercept is 0). 

However, the lattice plot showed that there's random intercepts...

Comment: The x-axis of the plot is labelled `1 + groupMCpres` which suggests that it was produced from a model with random intercepts. Having said that, it is possible that the plot is simply showing lines of best fit for each group, regardless of how the model is specified, so: How did you create the lattice plot ?